# Getting null pointer exception running a batch apex

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

I am getting an error like "Argument 1 cannot be null" while running this batch apex Batchupdate_Montly_DepthTracker. Please note this batch runs on result sets returned from a scheduled apex.

Assumption: Is it because I am running the batch apex class without running the scheduled apex and the result sets are not returned?

Please find class-  Batchupdate_Montly_DepthTracker

```
global class Batchupdate_Montly_DepthTracker implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
   public String query;
   // Record types for Deapth Tracker
   private String readonlyRecordtype = 'OAPI_HOS_Depth Tracker_Realonly';
   private String FirstdayRecordtype = 'OAPI_HOS_Depth Tracker_FirstDay';
   private String DefaultRecordtype = 'FutureMonth';


   global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
      return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
   }

   global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){

    list<Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c> dts = new list<Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c>();
    Map<String,Id> recordtypeforEndoftheMonth = new  Map<String,Id>();
    //Getting the Record types for Depth Tracker object
    for(RecordType rect: [SELECT Id,Name FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType = 'Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c']){
        recordtypeforEndoftheMonth.put(rect.name.touppercase(), rect.Id);
    }

     Date todaydate = Date.TODAY();
     for(sObject s : scope){Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c dt = (Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c)s;

        //For past Depth Trackers
         if( dt.End_Date_OAPI__c.isSameDay(todaydate) || dt.End_Date_OAPI__c < todaydate )  {
            dt.RecordTypeId = recordtypeforEndoftheMonth.get(readonlyRecordtype.toUpperCase());
            dt.Active_OAPI__c = false; 
            dts.add(dt);
          }
          //For Depth Trackers for current month
         else if(dt.Start_Date_OAPI__c.Month() == todaydate.month() && dt.Start_Date_OAPI__c.year() == todaydate.year() ){
            dt.RecordTypeId = recordtypeforEndoftheMonth.get(FirstdayRecordtype.toUpperCase());
            dt.Active_OAPI__c = true;
            dts.add(dt);
         }
         //Future Depth Trackers
         else{
            dt.RecordTypeId = recordtypeforEndoftheMonth.get(DefaultRecordtype.toUppercase());
            dt.Active_OAPI__c = true;
            dts.add(dt);
         }

      }

        try{
                    //update Contcts;
                    list<Database.Saveresult> sr = database.Update(dts);
                    system.debug('Saveresult' + sr);
                    Set<Id> scRows;
                    if(sr != null) {
                        scRows = new Set<Id>();
                        for(Database.SaveResult r : sr) {
                            if(r.isSuccess() == false) {
                             scRows.add(r.getId());
                            }
                        }
                        system.debug('Update failed for Depth Tracker: '+ scRows );
                    } 
            }
            catch(DMLException ex){
                System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR,'Error while trying to updating Depth Trackers. ' +ex.getStackTraceString());
            }
      //Update dts;
      }



   global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
   }
}
```

The scheduled batch code is as below

```
global class scheduledBatchableForDepthTrackerLock implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        Batchupdate_Montly_DepthTracker dtBatch = new Batchupdate_Montly_DepthTracker(); 
        dtBatch.query ='SELECT Id, End_Date_OAPI__c, Start_Date_OAPI__c, RecordTypeId FROM Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c';
        database.executebatch(dtBatch,50);

        Batchupdate_Montly_HCPDepthTracker HCPdtBatch = new Batchupdate_Montly_HCPDepthTracker();
        HCPdtBatch.query = 'SELECT Id, End_Date_OAPI__c, Start_Date_OAPI__c, RecordTypeId FROM HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c';
        database.executebatch(HCPdtBatch,50);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the line of Apex that is giving you that error?

Comment: return Database.getQueryLocator(query);   This is the line to return the result set @Daniel

Answer (score 1):

In you start method of the class the implements Database.Batchable you will need to return a database.querylocator using Database.getQueryLocator(query);

The error is indicating that the SOQL string `query` is null. Try setting this to a SOQL query that returns the records you want the batch to execute on.

```
global class Batchupdate_Montly_DepthTracker implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
   // You need to set this Member to a SOQL query.
   global String query;

   global Batchupdate_Montly_DepthTracker() {
       // Add the other fields you need to query and the where clause, etc...
       this.query = 'SELECT Id, End_Date_OAPI__c, Start_Date_OAPI__c, RecordTypeId FROM Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c';
   }


   global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
      System.assertNotEquals(null, query, 'The query should be defined');
      return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
   }

   global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) {
   }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: That query results are returning from a schedulable batch apex. Can you help me how to deal with it?

Comment: @saikat Do you want to use an iterable collection rather than a SOQL query to drive the batch?

Comment: I want to pass soql result sets from the schedulable apex batch to it's sub ordinate batch and perform update operations needed. I was running the subordinate batch from developer console to perform the above activity since schedulable batch is not run from developer console. Please let me know how to proceed here. @Daniel Please find the schedulable batch I have editted in the question section.

Comment: @saikat Either move the query into the constructor (it could be a parameter if required) and assert that is has a value. Or switch to returning Iterable from the start method and returning a List of sObjects.

Comment: Did the first option.Running successfully. Thanks Daniel!!

Comment: @saikat Great. There is a green check mark next to the answer that is used to indicate the question has been answered.